# Multiple paths for a accepting string in NFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

If a string(w) is accepted by an NFA, then corresponding to w, 
can there be multiple paths each starting from the start state and ending at an accepting state?

Comment: Alas, a bit late to invite you to present the results of your own efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be many paths from the starting state to the ending state. It is not too difficult to cook up many trivial examples of when this happens, for instance

[image: 2 Path NFA]

Clearly accepts the string $ab$ but it can go through either $s1$ or $s2$.

However, in DFA's this will never happen because at each state there is only a single possible transition for each character, and those fixed transitions uniquely determine the path.